# How to convert entire string to one item in list, not one character per item?

Tags: python, string, list

I'm not sure of the terminology so bear with me. I have `self.desc`.

```
>>> print (self.desc)
This is a string.
```

It can be multiple sentences and sometimes, but not always, this string needs to be split in sentences. Because of all the intricacies in determining what a sentence is, I used NLTK for this.

```
if splitme==True:
    self.desc = sent_tokenize(self.desc)
```

The problem is when I don't tokenize it I get `"This is a string."` and when I do I get `["This is a string."]`. So later on when I have to reference it I get:

Tokenized:

```
>>> print(self.desc[0])
[This is a string.]
```

Not tokenized:

```
>>> print(self.desc[0])
T
```

I know it's because when it is tokenized it's a list and not tokenized it's a string. I just don't know how to fix it. I tried converting the string to a list but then it just puts each character in a list:

```
>>> self.desc = list(self.desc)
>>> print (self.desc)
['T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'l', 'i', 's', 't', '.']
```

I'm not quite sure how to go about fixing this. I've looked for answers but maybe I'm not using the right search terms.

Comment: `self.desc = [self.desc]`?

Comment: Ugh! Yes, that's it. I didn't know I could do that. I tried `self.desc[]` just as a shot in the dark but that was obviously invalid syntax. Thanks.

Comment: You can't just do that. What if `self.desc` is already a list? You would have a list of lists! You need to perform a check first. See my answer

Comment: Yes, I understood that needing a check was implied. I already had a check later on in my code for something else. The brackets were the keys I was missing. But yes, your answer is complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `self.desc` is a list and, if it is not, you turn it into a list:

```
self.desc = [self.desc] if isinstance(self.desc, str) else self.desc
```

or you can do the opposite, and turn lists into strings:

```
self.desc = self.desc[0] if isinstance(self.desc, list) else self.desc
```

The rest of your code must act accordingly to the transformation you have performed.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Putting it in brackets was what I needed to do, thanks.